# Firebird connection using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, firebird

How to create a Firebird connection using Spring Boot to make views in SQL using the Firebird database? I have no idea how to build this.

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");
    Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:C:/DB/DASHBOARD.FDB","sysdba","masterkey");
    Statement stm= con.createStatement();
    ResultSet res= stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TBLEMPLOYEE");
    while (res.next()) {
        System.out.println("DASHBOARD LASTNAME:"
                + res.getString("LASTNAME"));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

I tried to make a connection string, but without success because Spring doesn't recognize it.

Comment: What is the exception stacktrace? (please use `e.printStackTrace()`). As an aside, the code as shown is plain Java/JDBC, not Spring Boot specific. Likely you haven't added Jaybird (the Firebird JDBC driver) to the dependencies.

Comment: I suggest you read a basic introduction on Spring Boot so you understand how the Spring Boot way of creating connections works. For example [How to: Data Access](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-access)

Comment: BTW: It looks like you created a new account. Was that intentional?

Answer (score 1):

Take the following steps:

1. Go to https://start.spring.io/
2. Configure it with Maven (or Gradle if you prefer that)
3. Enter the desired coordinates for your project
4. Add dependency JDBC
5. Click Generate and unpack the zip to a location on your computer
6. Open the project in you favorite IDE
7. In the pom.xml, in the `dependencies` section add Jaybird (the Firebird JDBC driver):

   ```xml
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
       <artifactId>jaybird</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```

   Or, if you used Gradle, add to the `dependencies` section of `build.gradle`:

   ```
   runtimeOnly 'org.firebirdsql.jdbc:jaybird'
   ```
8. In `src/main/resources/application.properties` add:

   ```ini
   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost/employee
   spring.datasource.username=sysdba
   spring.datasource.password=masterkey
   ```
9. In the package generated by the initializr (default `com.example.demo`), add a new class `SimpleRunner`:

   ```java
   package com.example.demo;

   import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

   import javax.sql.DataSource;

   @Component
   public class SimpleRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

       private final DataSource dataSource;

       public SimpleRunner(DataSource dataSource) {
           this.dataSource = dataSource;
       }

       @Override
       public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
           try (var connection = dataSource.getConnection();
                var stmt = connection.createStatement();
                var rs = stmt.executeQuery("select first_name, last_name from employee")) {
               while (rs.next()) {
                   System.out.printf("%s %s%n", 
                           rs.getString("first_name"), rs.getString("last_name"));
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

This very basic application will connect to the Firebird example database `employee`, and print out the first and last names of the employees in the `employee` table.

Answer (score 0):

In my application work with this application property:

```
spring:
  firebird-datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:C:\\my_app\\DB.FDB
    username: SYSDBA
    password: masterkey
    hikari:
      auto-commit: false
```